# Custom Search Page Filter Results

Tags: 2010, search, filter

I have created a custom search page with a core search web part. It builds a query string in URL to populate the search results. k=[keyword] is the first, then to narrow the search to specific business area we use u=https://domain/Business/Lists/TheList. This works well, but we need to filter the searches by the lists column.

So we may have a list that is populated with articles for numerous business areas, so we need to filter the results to a specific business area. Is there any way to do this through the URL?

So...https://domain/search.aspx?k=test&u=https://domain/Business/List&column name:column value?

Answer (score 1):

Tom,

I have written a blog for custom search in XSLTListViewWebPart, the list I am using is External List but same filters and javascript may be applied to any Custom List as well...

Please go through [this blog](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/)

It is a custom solution and not use any Core Search Result Web Part..

Answer (score 1):

You can specify property restrictions as part of the `k` query parameter just specify
`https://domain/search.aspx?k=test%20column1%3Dvalue1%20column2%3Dvalue2&u=https://domain/Business/List` (%3D is =)

For full syntax of keyword queries see [Keyword Query Syntax Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx) and more specific [Property Restriction Keyword Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394509.aspx)

In order for data to be available for search, they have to be exposed as managed properties in the Search Service Application. Search is a large and complicated topic, but for a start on managed properties you can look at [Manage metadata properties for search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097.aspx)

Comment: I just tried that, so my query looked like: https://domain/search.aspx?k=ANY(test)%20Business_x0020_Area%3DMy%20Area&u=https://domain/Business/List, but it didn't return any results when there is a list item called test with test written in it logged under the My Area Business Area.

Comment: Two things: you need quotes around "My Area" as it contains a space and you need to specify a managed property which is mapped to `Business Area`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but how would I go about doing that? Is it in the list settings? The company I am working for has given me admin access, but not complete site control. By default is it the generated columns when you create a list that are filterable?

Comment: Nothing in search happens by default. See addition to answer